# How can i pass ireport parameters to java method and how to use return value in my report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using  ireport tool in my application . There is a requirement to call java function from ireport tool . everything is ok but when i press "preview" button , ireport do nothing . ireport show me Just "design" window . please Help me
I have see this page 
[Writing methods in jasper report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470476/writing-methods-in-jasper-report)
and do all recommendations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The project folder is marked with a red exclamation mark. Check the _Problems_ view to see what the problem is.

Comment: No , red exclamation mark removed but the problem doesn`t solved

Comment: please help me if you can .

Comment: it seems ok, we need the error (stacktrace) message to help you.

Comment: yes . it seem ok . it doesn`t any error message . please Help me . i spent about 18 month on my program

Comment: maybe you could give me a java developer email that i can give him email about my serious problem or any other help . i`m confused

Comment: You need to improve the question, you probably have an error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself
I`ve to chenged`Date.Test.GreagoryToshamsi($F{datekh}) `to`Date.Test.GreagoryToshamsi($F{datekh}.toString())`